# Is i possible to drag and drop a file onto a Clutter actor?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, clutter

Is it possible in Clutter to drag a file from, lets say a file manager (Nautilus/Nemo) to an actor in the Clutter programs window and have it then do something with the file (URI)?

I looked it up and found Clutter.DragAction, but that looks like it is only for use inside the Clutter stage itself.

Please provide any examples in Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't directly accept drops from other applications. Clutter does not have a XDND implementation.

you can use clutter-gtk and implement drag and drop on a GtkClutterEmbed through the usual signals, as described on the GNOME wiki: https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeLove/DragNDropTutorial

Comment: Wow, you keep answering all my Clutter questions. Are you some sort of Clutter guru? lol.

I guess I keep forgetting that Clutter is a young project and can't do a lot of the things most other toolkits can.

Comment: I am not sure I qualify as "guru", but I am e Clutter toolkit maintainer, so I may be able to help, sometimes... :-)

Comment: also, I'd like to point out that some thing will not be implemented by Clutter regardless of its (relative) young age; one of them is the XDnD protocol, or a great deal of windowing system integration.

Comment: Anyways X will be hopefully replaced by GIR or Wayland.

Comment: I assume that by "GIR" you mean "Mir" — for which Clutter won't get a backend, unless somebody writes one and submits it for review. in any case, Clutter won't see DnD support even from Wayland, as far as I'm concerned.